# What are the affects of disabling CGI on my server to enable PHP CLI

Tags: php, php-cgi, php-cli

I have a DS WHM - cpanel running apache / with litespeed I have a number of websites running on this server  I need to run CLI on one of the sites the CGI module is enabled in the apache build.

The script I need to run has a configuration check -- and gives error PHP CLI not installed

If I check PHP -V     I get PHP 5.3.26 (cli) so it looks like PHP CLI is installed .but I cant seem to be able to enable CLI . my next idea is to disable CGI in apache but am not sure what the effect of this will be on other sites ..?

Can I run make install-cli ?   any ideas what I should do...

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the CLI PHP SAPI is installed, because you can run it.  Most likely the issue is that the configuration script or your CGI is running in a chroot and cannot find it; you need to determine where it expects the CLI to be (you may have to read through the config test script if this isn't documented anywhere), and make it available there in the CGI's environment.

That said, I would tend to be suspicious of a CGI which refuses to run under mod_php and instead requires the CLI SAPI.  This kind of thing usually indicates some sort of bad smell.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. yes but this is a specialist extension for a magento site so stuck with it...?